# Custom root module routing issue

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I am trying to add the custom root module as my initial boot strapping module and then from there I am routing to log in screen with the lazy load. Routing is not redirecting  to log in screen . You can find the code base from the below git hub link. Please look into the same and let me know where it is going wrong? Thanks in advance.
https://github.com/deepakkumarbarik/my-dream-app

Best Regards,
Deepak

Comment: Where is it rerouting ? does it infinitely load ?

Comment: You should post the significant parts of the code here.